# The Gemfile specifies no dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, rubygems

I'm trying to install the Sunspot gem. When I first tried to bundle install after adding the gems, I got back the following message for the first time:

```
$ bundle install
The Gemfile specifies no dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I disregarded the message and continued with the installation process. But the commands the guide told me to enter didn't work:

```
$ rails generate sunspot_rails:install
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /home/zoltan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -V, [--skip-action-view], [--no-skip-action-view]      # Skip Action View files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                     # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

And after that:

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
/home/zoltan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler    /rubygems_integration.rb:252:in `block in replace_gem': rake is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/zoltan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Is the initial Gemfile message related to these errors?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.12'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.2'
end

gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

Comment: Looks like it is. What's in your Gemfile? Is it empty?

Comment: No, and I don't believe I changed it recently except for adding the Sunspot gems. I added it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not currently in the directory that contains the Gemfile when you run bundle install. Be sure to CD to the directory where your Gemfile is located before running `bundle install`